# How to override 'org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements' property value inside a TomEE container?

Tags: xml-parsing, cxf, apache-tomee, stax, tomee-7

I've got a JAX-WS web service endpoint configured purely via annotations running in TomEE 7 environment. Basically, the method being called has to return a `List<String>` of all node names contained in a graph data structure. The response of such a request can contain more thank 50k elements.

With CXF 2.6.x this worked fine. However, when I call the WS-method under CXF 3.x (bundled in TomEE 7.x), the following exception is thrown on the server side:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:906)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:712)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:801)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1680)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1559)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:653)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy51.getAllNodeNames(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:485)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:855)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:894)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:892)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.push(InputElementStack.java:340)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2951)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2839)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1073)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
    ... 27 more
Error: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded
```

So far, I've read the official [CXF documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html) on this issue, checked a [HowTo at the TomEE](https://openejb.apache.org/developer/configuration/cxf.html) website and read many related, yet older posts in forums.

I tried to set the properties - as advised by the TomEE documentation - via `openejb-jar.xml` in the webservice's `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar>
 <ejb-deployment ejb-name="MyWebService">
   <properties>
     org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements = 100000
   </properties>
 </ejb-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```

I also tried with the shorter property `cxf.stax.maxChildElements` to check whether this would be accepted, yet without success.

For testing/debugging, I start the TomEE instance via the *tomee-maven-plugin*, Therefore, I tried the set the `maxChildElement` property as an environment property like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
        <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
        <debug>false</debug>
        <tomeeHttpPort>8181</tomeeHttpPort>
        <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
        <args>-Dfoo=bar</args>
        <skipCurrentProject>true</skipCurrentProject>
        <webapps>
            <webapp>my.ws:${webservice.artifact.name}:${webservice.artifact.version}?name=ws-endpoint</webapp>
        </webapps>
        <libs>
            <!-- Third party libraries needed in the global lib folder of TomEE -->
            <lib>log4j:log4j:${log4j.version}</lib>
        </libs>
        <systemVariables>
            <!--
                special property needed to allow for more childElements in StAX Parser
            -->
            <org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElement>100000</org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElement>
        </systemVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Sadly, it has no effect on the runtime configuration of CXF/StAX (Woodstox).

### Question

How can we override the `maxChildElements` property via a configuration in `openejb-jar.xml` or as an external property at TomEE startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got it working with the help of [Romain Manni-Bucau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874954/romain-manni-bucau) (credits to him for pointing me into the right direction). Yet, his original answer is not the final solution. Therefore, I give the working configuration here.

1.) Put the following `openejb-jar.xml` to the `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar>
    <ejb-deployment ejb-name="MyWebService">
        <properties>
            cxf.jaxws.properties = cxfConfig
        </properties>
    </ejb-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```

2.) Provide a new (or add to an existing) `resources.xml` file, again via `WEB-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <Service id="cxfConfig" class-name="org.apache.openejb.config.sys.MapFactory" factory-name="create">
        org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements = 100000
    </Service>
</resources>
```

Note well the configuration link via the `MapFactory` object with the id `cxfConfig`.

3.) Configure JAX-WS clients to set corresponding property as well. For instance, given a *Spring* client, this can be configured like so:

```
<bean id="wsClientProxy" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.acme.ws.jaxb.MyWebservice"/>
    <property name="address" value="${ws.endpoint.url}"/>
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="100000" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In general, this might also be useful for people trying to set other CXF-related properties as listed in the [XML section of the CXF security guideline](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/security.html#Security-XML), in particular to increase or decrease conservative default values.

I tested the above configuration steps successfully under a TomEE 7.0.3 and 8.0.9 environment, yet this should also reliably work with all 7.0.x and 8.0.x releases.

For other use cases, [this blog post by Romain](https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/tomee-webserviceref-and-configuration/) might also be worth reading, as it covers basic configuration concepts quite well.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2):

You can try
-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements=100000
It should also work

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a resources.xml with a Service of type (class-name) java.util.Properties and the properties inside:

1. openejb-jar.xml would get this property:

   cxf.jaxws.properties = cxfConfig
2. resources.xml would get

   org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements = 1

This test does it programmatically: https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/server/openejb-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/openejb/server/cxf/MaxChildTest.java

Comment: This results in `org.apache.openejb.config.NoSuchProviderException: Cannot determine a provider for Resource(id=ws-endpoint/cxfConfig, type=java.util.Properties, provider=null).`

Possible valid configurations might be: ... <list of available options>